# Cargar Textbox al seleccionar un item de un Combobox (cargado desde una base de datos)

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

aquí le muestro un problema que tengo desde varios días sin poder resolver, ver si me pueden ayudar con este problema.
tengo una base de datos con las siguientes informaciones:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo un **COMBOBOX** y un **TEXTBOX** lo que quiero conseguir es que al seleccionar un item del **COMBOBOX** este me pase el dato de la fila de **COSTO** al **TEXTBOX**.

Cargo el COMBOBOX de esta manera:

```
 private void FRUTAS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select*from tbFruta", conexion);
        conexion.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(dr.Read())
        {
            cbxFrutas.Items.Add(dr.GetString(1));
        }
        conexion.Close();
    }
```

Todo marcha bien, me carga todo en el **COMBOBOX**

Mi problema esta que al seleccionar un item del **COMBOBOX** este siempre me carga el ultimo valor de la fina COSTO que es 5.33 sin importar la seccion la repuestas en el **TEXTBOX** es la misma.

```
 private void cbxFrutas_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = "select costo from tbFruta";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexion);
        SqlDataReader myreader;
        try
        {
            conexion.Open();
            myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (myreader.Read())
            {
                tbxFrutas.Text = myreader["costo"].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            conexion.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Tienes que hacer un where en l consulta para que sea igual al texto del combo

Comment: Claro, porque no estas seleccionando nada del combo box, estas volviendo a realizar la consulta a la base de datos, y mientras pueda leer te trae el resultado, pero nunca le dijiste que queres leer, entonces te trae el ultimo porque ya recorrio todos.

Answer (score -1):

Cambia

```
string sql = "select costo from tbFruta";
```

por

```
string sql = "select costo from tbFruta where nombre='"+cbxFrutas.Text+"'";
```

Comment: falta una explicacion breve

Comment: @Joranome, gracias por tu repuestas igual a todos los demás, lo he probado así, el tema es que para poder presentarme el Ítem en el Textbox, debo seleccionarlo dos veces